# Inclusion relation of stalks of the structure sheaf of a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[image]

In the hint of the exercise in the photo, it claims the existence of an element f which is in the stalk of x and not in the stalk of Z. I want to know the how to prove it.
The exercise comes from hartshorne’s algebraic geometry. Ex 3.6.8.

Comment: Pick a point on $Z$ that is not $x$. Call it $y$. Any rational function on $x$ with a pole at $y$ but no pole at $x$ will do the trick.

Comment: @Ravi Thanks. But how to pick a rational function like you said. And even y is the pole of f, f can still in the stalk of Z.

Comment: An idea : Since $x \notin Z$ there is $f \in I_Z$ with $f(x) \neq 0$ (maybe you need to use explicitely that the scheme is separated or something like this). By a suitable transformation you can assume $f(x) = \infty$ and still $f_{|Z} = 0$, and now $1/f$ should do the trick.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Would you please give a detailed proof?